# Serialize/deserialize unsigned char

Tags: c++

I'm working on an API for an embedded device, and need to display an image generated (by the API). The screen attached to the device allows me to render bitmaps, with data stored as `unsigned char image[] = { 0B00000000, 0B00001111, 0B11111110... }`.

What is the easiest way to deserialize a string in whatever format needed?

My approach was to create a `stringstream`, separate by comma and push to `vector<char>`. However, the function to render bitmaps will only accept  `char`, and from what I can find online it seems to be quite difficult to convert it. Ideally, I'd rather not use a `vector` at all, as including it adds several kbs to the project, which is limited in size by both the download speed of the embedded device (firmware is transferred by EDGE) and the onboard storage.

Comment: I'm confused, why would you need to deserialize a string? What's the function signature of the function to render bitmaps?

Comment: more explanation and some sample code would be helpful to look into your issue....

Comment: @MarkRansom So the API will return a single string in a XML-like format, eg `<id>abc123</id><param>value</param><qr>{{imagedata}}</qr>..`, which is then stripped down to each param, so I'll have a `string qr = {{imagedata}}`. I then need to deserialize this imagedata string into a `char` array for the bitmap render function.

Comment: Will `qr.c_str()` work for you? If not, why?

Comment: @SergeiKulik As the API returns binary literals, `c_str()` would return `char image[] = { '0', 'B', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 'B', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1'... }` rather than `{ 0B00000000, 0B00001111... }`

Comment: Oh man, that's ugly. I can't imagine why a resource-constrained environment would use such a verbose interchange format. Are you *sure* that's what it returns?

Comment: @BenedictLewis those are just number representations. You can convert it later after the transferring. Rule of serialization is to minimize data as far as possible.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it sounds like you want to convert a string composed of a series of "0b00000000" style literals, comma separated, into an array of their actual values. The way I would do this is to:

1. Get the number of bytes in the image (I assume this is known from the string length?).
2. Create a `std::vector` of `unsigned char` to hold the results.
3. For each byte in the input, construct a `std::bitset` from the string value, and then get its actual value.

Here's a code example. Since you have said you'd rather not use `vector` I have used C-style arrays and strings:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    auto input = "0b00000000,0b00001111,0b11111111";
    auto length = strlen(input);

    // Get the number of bytes from the string length. Each byte takes 10 chars
    // plus a comma separator.
    int size = (length + 1) / 11;

    // Allocate memory to hold the result.
    std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> bytes(new unsigned char[size]);

    // Populate each byte individually.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        // Create the bitset. The stride is 11, and skip the first 2 characters
        // to skip the 0b prefix.
        std::bitset<8> bitset(input + 2 + i * 11, 8);

        // Store the resulting byte.
        bytes[i] = bitset.to_ulong();
    }

    // Now loop back over each byte, and output it to confirm the result.
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        std::cout << "0b" << std::bitset<8>(bytes[i]) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers. I'm getting two errors, "No match for operator + (type std::string and int)" at `std::bitset<8> bitset(qrcode + 2 + i * 11, 8);`, and "cannot convert `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>` to unsigned char in assignment".

Comment: Sounds like you're using a `std::string` where my example uses C strings. Try doing `auto input = my_string.c_str()`, or otherwise convert the example to use `std::string`.